# Создание таймера в событии таймера

Tags: c#, таймер

Дело в том, что по событию таймера `timer` должен вызываться самописный контрол , который в своей работе использует другой таймер, а именно - `FormTimer`.
Только вот этот `FormTimer` в этом контроле не отрабатывает (`Tick` событие никогда не происходит).

Если я правильно понимаю, то поток закрывается раньше срабатывания таймера.
Для теста вставил в конец события : `while(true){;}` , однако тики все равно не проходят...

Чего я не правильно понимаю и как все-таки решить данную проблему?

Спасибо

```
class Test{  
    private System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();  
    public Test() {  
        this.Run();  
    }  
    public void Run() {  
        timer.Interval = 1000;  
        timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);  
        timer.Start();  
    }  
    void timer_Elapsed(object sender,System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e) {  
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(sender.ToString()+" >>> "+System.DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());  
        System.Windows.Forms.Timer FormTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();  
        FormTimer.Interval = 1000;  
        FormTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(FormTimer_Tick);  
        FormTimer.Start();  
        /*  
        timer.Stop();  
        while(true) {;}  
        */  
    }  
    void FormTimer_Tick(object sender,EventArgs e) {  
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(sender.ToString() + " >>> " + System.DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());  
    }  
}
```

Comment: "Создание таймера в таймере"...рекурсия, однако =)

Comment: не сказал бы , что я этому рад )) помочь мне как то никто не может D:

Comment: У Вас по ходу по завершении обработчика timer_Elapsed ссылка на FormTimer становится не действительной и объект уничножается. Объявите FormTimer как член класса, должно сработать

Comment: The process or thread has changed since last step. Поищите в этом направлении.

Comment: Данил , в том то и дело , что обьявлять таймер , как член класса мне не очень хочется.Хотя если и сделать это , то ничего не изменится.Проблема в том что таймер винформовый , и вроде как должен запускаться в ui потоке. где он запускается у меня - не понятно 

Flash , у меня нет проблем с отладкой (или я неправильно вас понял  ?)

Comment: ![alt](http://habrastorage.org/storage2/0fa/b84/230/0fab842303fd7726f2e910bdc03ae7e7.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

проблему решил с помощью System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher

```
class Test {  
  private System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();  
  private System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher d;   
  private delegate void DeegateTest();  
  public Test() {  
    d = System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;  
    this.Run();  
  }  
  public void Run() {  
    timer.Interval = 1000;  
    timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);  
    timer.Start();  
  }  
  void timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e) {  
     System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(sender.ToString() + " >>> " +   System.DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());  
     d.BeginInvoke(new DeegateTest(ShowTestMessage),System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background, null);  
  }  
  void FormTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {  
     System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(sender.ToString() + " >>> " + System.DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());  
  }  
  void ShowTestMessage() {  
        System.Windows.Forms.Timer FormTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();  
        FormTimer.Interval = 1000;  
        FormTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(FormTimer_Tick);  
        FormTimer.Start();  
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблему помогает решить замена внутренних таймеров (а именно их тип) на System.Timers.Timer